# Trial is different in stripe gateway

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-cashier

I am using Cashier in Laravel 9 and trying to redirect the user to the stripe gateway with 14 days trial, but on the gateway, it shows 13 days. What can be the problem?

```
public function paymentForm(Plan $plan)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $subscription = $user
        ->newSubscription($plan->name, $plan->price_id);

    if($plan->trial) {
        $subscription->trialDays($plan->trial);
    }

   return $subscription->checkout([
    'success_url' => route('success_page').'?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    'cancel_url' => route('failed_page'),
]);

}
```

I tested this code by changing trial days, and here are my responses for the trial:

```
$subscription->trialDays(0); => returns 1
$subscription->trialDays(1); => returns 1
$subscription->trialDays(2); => returns 1
$subscription->trialDays(20); => returns 19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because of the difference between Stripe and Laravel Cashier trial periods. ***Stripe uses seconds to count the trial period and Laravel Cashier uses days.***

Use [`trialUntil()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/billing#subscription-trials)

```
if ($plan->trial) {
    $trialEnd = now()->addDays($plan->trial);
    $subscription->trialUntil($trialEnd);
}
```

Comment: try `$subscription->timezone('UTC')->trialDays($plan->trial);`

Comment: Use original answer code with timezone https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-change-the-timezone-in-a-laravel-application

Comment: Thanks for your answer I added one minute to my code and the issue resolved,
 $subscription->trialUntil(Carbon::now()->addDays($plan->trial)->addMinute()->setTimezone('UTC'));